# Post request inside click listener not redirectiong to the requested page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So in my html i am haveing an element

```
<button">Add to Cart</button>
```

For this button click functionality, i am doing it in the click listener in the script. My script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('click',function(e)
        {

            e = e || window.event;
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
            console.log("value of the element clicked== "+target.innerHTML);
            if(target.innerHTML=="Add to Cart" || target.innerHTML=="Remove From Cart")
            {
              var uris=target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("#uris").value;   
              var username=target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("#usernames").value;
              console.log("user name=="+username); 
              console.log(target);
              if(target.innerHTML=="Add to Cart")
              {
                console.log("it is comming here");  
                var productid=target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("#proid").innerHTML;
                $.post('AddCart1',{product:productid,username:username,uri:uris}, function () {
                });
              } 
              else
              { 
                var productid=target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("#proid").value;
                console.log("parent id=="+productid); 
                $.post('RemoveItem',{product:productid,username:username,uri:uris}, function () {
                });
              }
            }   
        }, false);
</script>
```

So when i click the button i am getting the log "it is comming here". And also all the updates i am doing in my database are reflecting in my DB. But the page is not getting redirected to the requested url. It is remaining in the same page without reloading. What is the issue?

Comment: add Callback function( done ) to **$.post** , inside that function write redirect url(window.location = 'redirect_url').

Comment: Also, consider adding the event listener directly on the buttons, it'll make your code cleaner.

Comment: It worked fine thanq @SaravananN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi what i can see is you are not doing anything to redirect the page
so when you send request using $.post it will return you responce from requested page and you will b on same page.

```
to redirect you can use following methods
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("your url");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "your url";
```

you can use it inside your $post request on success of post request you can redirect to other page or you can even redirect without $.post.

Or

After including JQuery and the jquery.redirect.min.js plug-in, you can simply do something like this:

```
$().redirect('your url', {post data in key value pair i.e.'key':'value'});
```

and i also come across this may it work!

```
$.redirectPost("your URL", {post data in key value pair i.e.'key':'value'});
```

Comment: great! Happy coding  :-)